# How to disable downloading a file from your web without a session variable?

Tags: php

I would like to disable downloading a file from my web without a download script (I'm using a direct URL like http://something/file.zip) unless you're registered, with PHP preferably.

Comment: enclose your download script with an `if` statement.  and also can you add your download script?

Comment: The problem is that I don't have a download script xD. The file downloads when you enter the URL (for example: http://something/file.zip)

Comment: Don't allow direct access to the file.  Secure it behind a script and check for your condition(s) within that script.

Comment: What do you mean you don't have a download script?

Comment: @David And how can I do that? Modifying .htaccess file or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, **don't allow direct access to the file**.  Store it *outside* of your web application's root folder, elsewhere on the file system, so that there is no link which can be used to download it.  This is because direct access skips any PHP application and interacts only with the web server, which has no knowledge of your application's session values.

Then create a "download" script to serve the file to users.  Generally such a script would be given some identifier for the file, something like:

```
http://yourserver.com/download.php?file=file.zip
```

(**Important:** *Be very careful* how you identify that file.  *Do not* just blindly let users download whatever they want, or they can enter longer paths onto the URL and download *any file* from your server.  *Always validate* access to things first.)

This would be just like any other PHP script, except that instead of displaying HTML it would return a file.  The actual part of outputting the file can be as simple as:

```
readfile('/path/to/file.zip');
```

You'd also likely want to set content headers appropriately, etc.  A more complete example can be found [in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php):

```
<?php
$file = 'monkey.gif';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```